# Assignment operator and "this" keyword

Tags: java, theory

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class Parent {
    Parent() {
        this = new Child();
    }
}
class Child extends Parent { }
```

The above would throw a syntax error: `The left hand side of an assignment operator must be a variable`

In java, the `this` keyword stores the memory address of the current calling object. I wish to overwrite the current object with an instance of the class' subclass. I understand the above snippet is throwing an error as `this` is not a variable and is probably immutable.

However, I wish to know why java doesn't allow this above feature? Is there any downside to it?

**EDIT**: This question occurred to me with reference to a Natural Language Processing (NLP) context. For example, in the French language, every verb has to end with 'er', 'ir' or 're'. All verbs have certain features in common. However, every verb must be either one of the three types mentioned above. So in the constructor of the parent class 'Verb', I want to categorize the object created as an 'ErVerb', 'IrVerb' or 'ReVerb'.

Comment: It doesn't make sense and even if this particular code would work, it'd throw a StackOverflowException.

Comment: How does the class know it's subclass? which is yet to be born? :P

Comment: What exactly do you want to reach?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is how confusing it can be. If I create a `Parent` object, I expect it to actually be a `Parent` object, instead of a `Child` object. If I want a `Child` object, I'll create one explicitly.

Comment: You probably want to have a factory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: @forgivenson What if there was a scenario where your Parent class was simply a common link among all the derived classes? At some point in your program, the Parent object would be useful, but later you needed that same object to become a Child object.

Answer (score 7):

There are two scenarios:

If you let `this` be instantiated to any `Object` whatsoever, not necessarily one in the type hierarchy, then an instantiation would have no guarantee about the contents of its reference. This breaks a couple things, most notably the entire concept of object-oriented programming.

If you restrict `this` to be instantiated to any subclass of the parent class, then that subclass constructor would call the parent constructor infinitely many times, causing a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: I had your second scenario in mind when I posed the question. If it wasn't compulsory in Java for every child class to call it's parent class' constructor, would the above snippet be possible? I have never liked the fact that java makes it compulsory for the constructor of every child class to call the parent class' constructor.

Comment: Removing the child constructor flow would cause other things to break from an object oriented standpoint. Object state needs to be rigidly maintained, and OO dictates that each parent object should be responsible for maintaining its own state independent of its child classes. Here's something else to think about - Imagine class A with children B and C. Suppose in the constructor of A you flipped a coin and wrote `this = new B()` or `this = new C()`. Until runtime, you can't be sure of the type - but *neither can the JVM*. So what could the compiler do? What methods could be accessible? Etc

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't make any sense to construct a subclass instance inside the parent's constructor and substitute the actual parent instance with the created child instance.

Despite the nasty `StackOverflowError` pointed out in the comments and in the other answer, there's no use case for doing this. In general, it's absurd (from the logical point of view) to create a child while creating the parent.

Consider the following *reasoning*:

*A specific car is being assembled in a factory. The process to assemble a specific car consists of many steps.*

*Some of these steps only occur when assembling the specific car, while others occur both when assembling the specific car and when assembling other vehicles, such as a specific van.*

*Now let's suppose that one of these general steps that occur when assembling many vehicles (including both the specific car and the specific van), indicates that we must assemble a new specific van and let it be the general vehicle being assembled.*

*Now, the specific car we were assembling would have become this new specific van. But it's impossible for a car to be a van => **ABSURD**.*

Comment: This question occurred to me with reference to a Natural Language Processing (NLP) context. For example, in the French language, every verb has to end with 'er', 'ir' or 're'. All verbs have certain features in common. However, every verb must be either one of the three types mentioned above. So in the constructor of the parent class 'Verb', I want to categorize the object created as an 'ErVerb', 'IrVerb' or 'ReVerb'. Hence this feature seemed useful for me.

Comment: Now I understand your motivation for the question. In OO design, hierarchy relations aren't modeled that way, though. You always create an object of a certain class and this remains the same until the object no longer exists. The class of the object is not a categorization. You can't model the class with an attribute, such as the type of French verb.